# Why isn't .save for Mongoose working in ReactJS?

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, reactjs, mongoose

I have a ReactJS and Redux connected to MongoDB, Mongoose.

I have a Mongoose Schema (user.js) set up like so:

```
var UserSchema = new Schema({
  email: {
    type: String,
    lowercase: true,
    unique: true,
    required: true
  },
})
```

And a API controller that receives the email string request, and then if nothing is entered in the text field, it sends a 422 error, and inside `User.findOne`, if the email already exists in the database, then it throws a 422 error and if not, does `user.save` to save it in the database.

```
"use strict";

const User = require('../models/user')

exports.register = function(req, res, next) {
  const email = req.body.email;
  console.log('ERROR 1')

  if(!email) {
    return res.status(422).send({ error: 'You must enter an email address.'})
    console.log('ERROR 1')
  }

  User.findOne({ email: email }, function(err, existingUser) {
    if(err) { return next(err); }
    console.log('ERROR 2')
    if(existingUser) {
      return res.status(422).send({ error: 'That email address is already in use.'})
    }
    console.log('ERROR 3')
    let user = new User({
      email: email,
    })
    console.log('ERROR 4')
    user.save(function(err, user) {
      if(err) { return next(err); }
      console.log('ERROR 5')
      res.status(201).json({
        user: user,
      })
    })
  })
  console.log('ERROR 6')
}
```

And I am making a POST request as such:

```
export function registerUser({ email }) {
  return function(dispatch) {
    axios.post(`${API_URL}/auth/register`, { email })
    .then(response => {
      console.log('THIS IS TESTING PURPOSE')
      console.log(response)
      dispatch({ type: AUTH_USER });
    })
    .catch((error) => {
      errorHandler(dispatch, error.response, AUTH_ERROR)
    });
  }
}
```

I made several POST requests and all get successful status back from API with sever config: `{'database': 'mongodb://localhost/practicedb',
  'port': process.env.PORT || 3000}`, yet the data never gets saved and database (practicedb) doesn't show up on Terminal.

Everything seem to be set up correctly but why the problem? Could I be missing something? Any insight or guidance would be really appreciated.

Thank you in advance!

**Here are some logs and what's OPTIONS request that I never made:**

[image]

Tried registering with same email again:
[image]

Comment: The OPTIONS request is probably done automatically by the request/AJAX plugin you're using. Or perhaps it's done by the browser. It's normal.

Comment: @Noah Hm then what could be the issue that the data is not being saved to the database? Everything seem to be set up correctly.

Comment: is it for brevity that you omit `var mongoose = require('mongoose');
var Schema = mongoose.Schema;`?

Comment: @MarcelDjaman if you are referring to the `user.js`, then yes and already have them defined.

Comment: @Noah any idea on it? Still stuck with no luck

Comment: @MarcelDjaman I'm still having trouble with no solution. Any thoughts?

Comment: Nothing come in my mind except debugging. Make sure you can query the database

Comment: @MarcelDjaman Could you show an example so I can accept the answer and upvote?

Comment: Asynchronous is what it comes to my mind

Comment: @MarcelDjaman Could you show for clarification?

Comment: check in your database if user document is persisted

Comment: @MarcelDjaman Sorry but could you clarify on what user document represents and what you mean by persistance?

Comment: @LyManeug Sorry, I didn't even know you could use Mongoose in the browser ;)

Answer (score 0):

Correct if i'm wrong but your bare save method is not async. Save method return a promise. See http://mongoosejs.com/docs/promises.html

**EDIT**

```
user.save().then(function(doc) {
    if (!doc) { next(new Error('Error while persisting!')); } 
    console.log('ERROR 5');

    res.status(201).json({
        user: doc
    });
});
```

You can also achieve this with any promised library ([Q](https://github.com/kriskowal/q), [bluebird](https://github.com/petkaantonov/bluebird/)) or use [ES6 Promise](http://exploringjs.com/es6/ch_promises.html). Alternatively use async.

Example with [Q](https://github.com/kriskowal/q). **NOT TESTED**:

```
"use strict";

const User = require('../models/user');
const Q = require('Q'); //add https://github.com/kriskowal/q

exports.register = function(req, res, next) {
  const email = req.body.email;
  console.log('ERROR 1')

  if(!email) {
    return res.status(422).send({ error: 'You must enter an email address.'})
    console.log('ERROR 1')
  }

  var deferred = Q.defer();
  User.findOne({ email: email }, function(err, existingUser) {
    if(err) { return next(err); }
    console.log('ERROR 2')
    if(existingUser) {
      return res.status(422).send({ error: 'That email address is already in use.'})
    }
    console.log('ERROR 3')
    let user = new User({
      email: email,
    })
    console.log('ERROR 4')
    user.save(function(err, user) {
      if(err) { 
          deferred.reject(err);
          return next(err); 
      }
      console.log('ERROR 5')
      deferred.resolve(user); //
    });

    res.status(201).json({
        user: deferred.promise,
      })
  })
  console.log('ERROR 6')
}
```

Comment: I am following this to practice https://github.com/joshuaslate/mern-starter/blob/d5231796d987b3cdb7d81b30fcc7a97bcec89774/server/controllers/authentication.js#L28-L65 and how is he able to successfully use .save?